# How to get a shelve set from closed review

Tags: tfs, unshelve

Below is the scenario 
1) I got code review suggestion
2) I worked on those suggestions.
3) I closed the Code review request to send a new code review request. 
4) But I Did NOT sent any Code review Request. As I remember I forgot to add one Nuget Package. So I tried to add it, but it did nt worked as expected, so I uninstalled some dependent packages as well :|

Can I get the code at stage 3 ? I can not see the Request in Code reviews to unshelve as its closed.

Can someone guide me here ?

Answer (score 1):

You could select `Recently finished` in your `Code Reviews`, find the code review that you need, open the code review and click `View Shelveset`. Check the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: I guess this is visible only if Manual Shelve set was created.

Comment: What's your situation?